# List all merged branches into current branch

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I want to list out all branches that are merged into the current branch.

I used `git branch --merged` command to list out branch names.

But it is listing all previous branches that I haven't merged into the current branches also.

Eg.

```
   master
     |
     ------------
     |     |    |
    dev   dev1  dev2
     |
   release
     |
    -----------------
    |        |      |
   feat1    feat2   next-release = feat1 + feat2 (merged)
```

Now say, I am currently in next-release branch.

When I `git branch --merged`, aren't only `feat1` and `feat2` branches should only be listed. Since only these two branches are merged into `next-release` branch.

But instead, all branches are listed.

```
master
dev
dev1
dev2
release
feat1
feat2
*next-release
```

Please help me understand this.

Comment: please show the graph, how your actual branch situation looks like and which commits are unmergen in your opinion. Thx.

Comment: This sound strange... have you checked against `git branch` if you are really in next-release?

Comment: @ErniBrown yeah.. `git branch --merged next-release` and `git branch` both show the same results..